# How to set button position fixed after orientation change

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I have a JQuery mobile application that is running on a tablet. But my problem is that my button (SEARCH) losses position and I would have to drag the screen if I want to see it when the tablet orientation is in landscape. How do I make sure it is still visible on both potrait and on landscape?

```
<div id="divBody" data-role="page" data-theme="c">

            <div data-role="header" class="hesto">         
                  <h1>Weld Splice </h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">   
                  <div> <input type="text" name="text-1" id="txtBarcode"      class="barcodeTxt"  placeholder="Scan barcode" value=""/></div> 
                  <div id="divButton"> <a href="#" id="btnBarcode" data-role="button"   data-iconpos="right" data-inline="true">Search</a></div> 
            </div>

            <div id="divFooter" data-role="footer" >

            </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap each one - input and button - with `div` class `ui-grid-solo`

```
<div class="ui-grid-solo">
 <input type="text" name="text-1" id="txtBarcode" class="barcodeTxt" placeholder="Scan barcode" value="" />
</div>
<div class="ui-grid-solo">
 <div id="divButton"><a href="#" id="btnBarcode" data-role="button" data-iconpos="right" data-inline="true" data-icon="search">Search</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

- **Reference:** [Grids - JQM v1.3.0](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/grids/)

Answer (score 0):

If the button is getting pushed down why not placed it in the header bar??

If you are ok with the approach you may change something as below

```
<div id="divBody" data-role="page" data-theme="c">
    <div data-role="header" class="hesto">
         <h1>Weld Splice </h1>
 <a href="#" id="btnBarcode" data-role="button" data-iconpos="right" class="ui-btn-right">Search</a>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="text-1" id="txtBarcode" class="barcodeTxt" placeholder="Scan barcode" value="" />
        </div>
        <div id="divButton"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="divFooter" data-role="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Check out a live fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/DuReF/